# How to scrape data from a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, extract

There's a webpage which is an interactive version of a dataset where you can view an data example and a few associated labels in boxes. I'm trying to get this data into a pandas dataframe where I extract the example and all the associated labels. The data is divided over multiple pages and has fixed boxes for each label that I want to extract.

I have never done such a thing before so I was wondering if there's any way to efficiently do this in Python? What libraries should I be looking at?

Here's an example of a sample that I'd like to extract:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different libraries depending on exactly how the data looks. But a few of those are just using pandas directly, beautifulsoup4, or selenium.

I would not suggest using pandas for web scraping if you expect to eventually scrape anything more, tho it is okay as a fast alternative if the HTML is structured in a good way and you do not need to interact with the webpage.

[beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) is what I would guess is the best choice because it is easy to use and is meant for extracting information from HTML.

[selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) would be a good choice if you can not access the data directly from HTML, or you need to actually interact with the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There exist many ways to scrape data from a web site, it's important to choose the best technology according to the site you want to scrape, you could choose the scrapper between the most popular like [Scrapy](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy), [BeautifulSoup4](https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4), [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright) or any other that allows you to extract what you want from a site, in the other hand you may choose some tools ton help you to post-process or store the extracted data like Pandas, [Redis](https://redis.io/).

It is highly recommended if you are going to scrape a large amount of data to use an infrastructure that helps you with this process, like [estela](https://github.com/bitmakerla/estela) that provides all the mechanisms to have successful data extraction.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Estela? I don't see your name among the contributors but all of you seem to be centered around Arequipa. Please review the [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)